# Javascript function returning value before execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cassandra, async-await

I am writing chat application using `Node.Js` and `Cassandra`. At backend after calling function `saveDataToCassandra` it is returning back before saving data to `Cassandra`. Is it `Cassandra` issue or `Javascript` issue? My `app.js` snippet is:

```
const cassandra = require('./routes/cassandra');
....
let result = cassandra.saveDataToCassandra(reqData);
console.log(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
```

My `cassandra.js` snippet is:

```
var saveDataToCassandra = (req) => {
    const roomId = req.roomId;
    const roomName = req.roomName;
    let participants = [];
    participants = req.participant;
    console.log("participant's list",participants);
    const formatted_date  = req.roomCreationTimestamp;

    var query = `insert into chat_app.chat_rooms(room_id,room_name,participant_type,participant,role,room_creation_date) values (?,?,?,?,?,?);`;
    participants.forEach((participant) => {
        var params = [roomId, roomName, participant.type, participant.username,participant.role, formatted_date];
        console.log(`params: ${params}`);
        client.execute(query,params,{prepare: true},(error, result) => {
            if(error){
                console.log(`error in inserting: ${error}`);
                genericResponse['status'] = "error";
                genericResponse['message'] = error;
                genericResponse['responseObject'] = {
                    roomId: roomId,
                    userName: participant.username
                };
                console.log(`generic response error: ${JSON.stringify(genericResponse)}`);
            }
            else {
                console.log(`insert result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
                genericResponse['status'] = "success";
                genericResponse['message'] = "Successfully Inserted!";
                genericResponse['responseObject'] = {
                    roomId: roomId,
                    roomName: roomName,
                    participant: participant.username
                }
                console.log(`generic response success: ${JSON.stringify(genericResponse)}`);    
            }
        });
    });
    console.log(`generic response before returning: ${JSON.stringify(genericResponse)}`);
    return genericResponse;
}
```

Issue:

```
participant's list [ { username: 'alice',
    role: 'teacher',
    type: 'Owner' },
  { username: 'bob',
    role: 'student',
    type: 'participant' } ]
params:
    791c6abfaa962ca60abb776d04d89a32937024f5, alice&bob, Owner,alice,teacher,2019-12-12 17:33:54
params: 
    791c6abfaa962ca60abb776d04d89a32937024f5, alice&bob,participant,bob,student,2019-12-12 17:33:54
generic response before returning: {"status":"","message":"","responseObject":""}
result: {"status":"","message":"","responseObject":""}
insert result: {"info":{"queriedHost":"127.0.0.1:9042","triedHosts":{"127.0.0.1:9042":null},"speculativeExecutions":0,"achievedConsistency":10,"isSchemaInAgreement":true},"columns":null,"pageState":null}
generic response success: {"status":"success","message":"Successfully Inserted!","responseObject":{"roomId":"791c6abfaa962ca60abb776d04d89a32937024f5","roomName":"alice&bob","participant":"alice"}}
insert result: {"info":{"queriedHost":"127.0.0.1:9042","triedHosts":{"127.0.0.1:9042":null},"speculativeExecutions":0,"achievedConsistency":10,"isSchemaInAgreement":true},"columns":null,"pageState":null}
generic response success: {"status":"success","message":"Successfully Inserted!","responseObject":{"roomId":"791c6abfaa962ca60abb776d04d89a32937024f5","roomName":"alice&bob","participant":"bob"}}
```

Now issue is `saveDataToCassandra` is returning `genericResponse` first and then data is stored on `Cassandra`. I want to return the response after saving data to `Cassandra`. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi all, can you please provide the solution using async/await??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the way you have structured your code is not write. You are calling a callback style function in foreach loop and when you are calling your method, you are not waiting. If you extract the execute method like this

```
function execute(participant, query) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.execute(query,params,{prepare: true}, (error, result) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(`error in inserting: ${error}`);
        genericResponse['status'] = "error";
        genericResponse['message'] = error;
        genericResponse['responseObject'] = {
            roomId: roomId,
            userName: participant.username
        };
        console.log(`generic response error: ${JSON.stringify(genericResponse)}`);
        reject(genericResponse);
    }
    else {
        console.log(`insert result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
        genericResponse['status'] = "success";
        genericResponse['message'] = "Successfully Inserted!";
        genericResponse['responseObject'] = {
            roomId: roomId,
            roomName: roomName,
            participant: participant.username
        }
        console.log(`generic response success: ${JSON.stringify(genericResponse)}`); 
        resolve(genericResponse);   
    }
  });
});
```

Change your save method like this - basically use promise all instead of foreach

```
var saveDataToCassandra = (req) => {
  const roomId = req.roomId;
  const roomName = req.roomName;
  let participants = [];
  participants = req.participant;
  console.log("participant's list",participants);
  const formatted_date  = req.roomCreationTimestamp;

  var query = `insert into chat_app.chat_rooms(room_id,room_name,participant_type,participant,role,room_creation_date) values (?,?,?,?,?,?);`;
  return Promise.all(participants.map(participant => {
      var params = [roomId, roomName, participant.type, participant.username,participant.role, formatted_date];
      console.log(`params: ${params}`);
      return execute(participant, query);
  }));
};
```

and use then when you need a result

```
const cassandra = require('./routes/cassandra');

cassandra.saveDataToCassandra(reqData)
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

You could also use async/await but this example is using promises. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ashsih! Can you please do me a favour and  explain this solution using `async/await` ? Thank you again